# mocking active record invalid exception with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec3

I'm mocking active record invalid exception in the rspec.

here is the method im facing problem with. image_processing_error checks for the errors of the image object.

```
def save_image(image)
  begin
    image.save!
      { message: I18n.t("messages.image_saved") , status: 200 }
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
      image_processing_error(image)
  end
end

private

def image_processing_error(image = nil)
  if image && image.errors.any? && image.errors.messages.any?
    { message: image.errors.messages.values[0][0] , status: 422 }
  else
    { message: I18n.t("errors.invalid_request"), status: 422 }
  end
end
```

And here is my rspec for the same

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe ImagesService do
  describe ".save_image" do
    context "save image throws error" do
      let(:image) { double("image", { "errors": { "messages": { "name": ["is invalid", "must be implemented"]}}}) }

      before do
        allow(image).to receive(:save!).and_raise(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
      end
      subject { described_class.save_image(image) }
      it "raised the error" do
        // I want to test the **ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
        // I places NoMethodError to just pass the test
        expect { subject }.to raise_error NoMethodError
        expect { subject }.to raise_error ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I'm getting below error when i read the image error. what is the proper double value i have to keep it to work.

```
Failures:

  1) ImagesService.save_image save image throws error raised the error
     Failure/Error: expect { subject }.to raise_error ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
     
       expected ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, got #<NoMethodError: undefined method `messages' for {:messages=>{:name=>["is invalid", "must be implemented"]}}:Hash> with backtrace:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the reason why you are not getting an exception on the call to `subject` is because an exception is not raised by it. Since you have set a rescue block in the `save_image`, if an exception is thrown inside of it, the rescue block will be called and the exception is not going to be propagated to the caller instead `image_processing_error` is going to be called.

So in your spec, when you call `subject` you are not going to get an exception but instead, you are going to get the parsed errors from `image_processing_error` which as I understand is actually the expected behavior.

In this case, what you could do is to test that the result you are getting from `subject` match with the expected error message that you would get in this case, something like:

```
it "returns the error messages" do
    expect(response.body).to include("is invalid", "must be implemented")
end
```

Comment: that makes sense. but i also see there is dot syntax used which might be incorrect. image_processing_error implementation seems to be incorrect for me as it has many . syntax for hash.

for instance the error i pasted from my spec not able to read the hash.